# IntelliSense -> Enter AutoComplete for every language - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense, enter

How to put the input of the first prompt on Enter from IntelliSense in Visual Studio?
For example, `for C++` there is make so easy just change `Member List Commit Aggressive` to `True` at the settings, but how it make for other languages?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on my side, and the default setting(IntelliSense) of C# highlighted and selected the default first prompt on Enter. Also tested with VB, it seems sometimes, under specific circumstances, the IntelliSense will not select the first prompt in the list, but select the most recommended code. If you continue to type more codes, the result will be the only (first) one.

Did you change some settings of IntelliSense in VS or install some extensions?

Please try to disable extensions temporary or/and [reset settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings), choose `General` on step 4, and see if it works.